# Running terminal commands from python script (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am trying to write a python script that does a few things:

1. Open a terminal, cd's to a directory, and run's a command there.
2. Open a second terminal, cd's to another directory, and executes a file there.

The execution of step 1 can only be completed after step 2 has been completed. Step 1 and 2 should both be done from a python (or another language) script.

I tries using subprocess.Popen, subprocess.call, os.sytem, but this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

The code I have so far:

```
import subprocess

terminal1 = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal",'cd ~',"torcs -r ~/quickrace.xml"])
terminal2 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal','cd ~'])
```

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: What do you mean by *"does not seem to work"*? What happens actually? And yes, please also post the code you've tried.

Comment: Why do you need a terminal?

Comment: I need to run several commands to automate the process of starting a torcs game and running a script. When this race is over I need to do the same again.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you would need a terminal for that. Does the user have to interact somehow with the terminal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633738/starting-gnome-terminal-with-arguments

Comment: running commands doe not necessarilymean open a terminal.

Comment: Running things in separate terminal windows sounds like a terrible idea. Probably don't open a terminal at all.  If you do, run the first set of commands, followed by the second set of commands, in the same terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly what you want but try it, replace the $variables by what you want and i think it will run.

```
#!/bin/bash


xterm -e "pwd ; cd $PATH ; your command ; echo press RETURN to close this window ; read" # delete the echo and the read to don't stop the process and make it run quickly
xterm -e "pwd ; cd $OTHERPATH ; your command ; echo press RETURN to close this window ; read"
```

And think to install xterm if you don't have. (rpm -i xterm if you have rpm packages)

In python i made this but it's not exactly what you want, but it's a beginning i think.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system('xterm -e "pwd ; cd $PATH ; your command ; echo press RETURN to close this window ; read" &') # delete the echo and the read to don't stop the process and make it run quickly
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    os.system('xterm -e "pwd ; cd $OTHERPATH ; your command ; echo press RETURN to close this window ; read" &')
```

Comment: Question was asked for python script

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! Now my final question is whether it is possible to run this in a loop. Such that both windows automatically close when the processes are finished and when they are both closed they should start again. Is that possible?

Comment: It is but it's harder, you can place it in a while (true)  with a sleep(x secondes) at the place of the input, but it's not a really good solution.The good solution could be to check the PID (processus ID) of the terms (it's a value which indicate the processus within run the xterm) and when the processus is over you start the next, so a while which contain a while which look the PID of xterm and close xterm when it's over and start a second xterm in a while.
I'm at my work and i'm not a big hardcoder python so i can't check it now sorry. But here is my mind.